# Unity2d: enemies won't spawn at random spawnpoint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawning

In unity I want when the game starts that the enemies spawn at a random spawnpoint 
(I made 3 spawn points in the game) but the enemies don't spawn at one of the points.

what did I do wrong?

Here is my code:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class WaveSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

public enum Spawnstate {SPAWNING, WAITING, COUNTING };

[System.Serializable]
public class Wave
{
    public string name;
    public Transform enemy;
    public int count;
    public float rate;

}

public Wave[] waves;
private int nextWave = 0;


public float timeBetweenWaves = 5f;
public float waveCountdown;

public Transform[] spawnPoints;

private float searchCountdown = 1f;

private Spawnstate state = Spawnstate.COUNTING;

void Start()
{
    if (spawnPoints.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No spawn points referenced");
    }
    waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;
}

void Update()
{
    if(state == Spawnstate.WAITING)
    {
        if(!EnemyIsAlive())
        {
            WaveCompleted();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    if(waveCountdown <= 0)

    {
        if(state != Spawnstate.SPAWNING)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnWave(waves[nextWave]));
        }

    }
    else
    {
        waveCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

void WaveCompleted()

{
    Debug.Log("Wave Completed!");

    state = Spawnstate.COUNTING;
    waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;

    if (nextWave + 1 > waves.Length - 1)

    {
        nextWave = 0;
        Debug.Log("Completed all waves!");
    }

    else
    {
        nextWave++;
    }



}

bool EnemyIsAlive()
{
    searchCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (searchCountdown <= 0f)
    {
        searchCountdown = 1f;
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy") == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


IEnumerator SpawnWave(Wave _wave)
{
    Debug.Log("Spawning Wave: " + _wave.name);
    state = Spawnstate.SPAWNING;

    for(int i = 0; i < _wave.count; i++)
    {
        SpawnEnemy(_wave.enemy);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f/ _wave.rate);
    }

    state = Spawnstate.WAITING;


    yield break;
}

void SpawnEnemy(Transform _enemy)

{
    Debug.Log("Spawning Enemy: " + _enemy.name);


    Transform _sp = spawnPoints[ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length) ];
    Instantiate(_enemy, transform.position, transform.rotation);

}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to change

```
Transform _sp = spawnPoints[ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length) ];
Instantiate(_enemy, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

to something like

```
Transform _sp = spawnPoints[ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length-1) ];
Instantiate(_enemy, _sp.position, _sp.rotation);
```

Comment: No problem. 
As mentioned by Rian, your code was prone to IndOutOfRance Except.
Also the transform you were passing was not the transformm you returned from your random spawn point parsing

Answer (score 1):

Random.Range returns inclusive range values, so 0 to 5 could include 0 and 5.

An array index is zero based so and array with 5 elements would have 0 to 4.

So in your SpawnEnemy method when you call

```
spawnPoints[ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length) ]
```

If Random.Range provides `spawnPoints.Length` it will fail.

Changing it to

```
spawnPoints[ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length-1) ]
```

Should fix your problem.